# incorrect syntax near keyword end in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE M_SelectStockIN @FarmID   int, 
                                 @ItemName varchar(50), 
                                 @InType   varchar(5) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      select ( Sum(( m.Item_Qty )) - total ) As InStock, 
             * 
      from   (select Sum(d.Use_Qty) as total 
              from   MoryaSales m 
                     inner join DailyFarmEntry d 
                             on m.batchID = d.FarmID 
              where  m.batchID = @FarmID 
                     and d.FarmID = @FarmID 
                     and m.Tr_Type = @InType 
                     and d.In_Type = @InType 
                     and m.Item_Name = @ItemName 
                     and d.ItemName = @ItemName) 
  END 

RETURN
```

I need help to fix that error:
  When we run the above stored procedure, the error " 
    incorrect syntax" occurs near keyword `end`

Comment: Remove that `RETURN` keyword after `END`

Comment: @Rahul it is unnecessary but that isn't the cause of the error.

Comment: I remove the return keyword but not working...

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

Remove `RETURN` and put an alias on the inner query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE M_SelectStockIN
    @FarmID int,
    @ItemName varchar(50),
    @InType varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN        
select 
    (sum((m.Item_Qty)) - total) As InStock,
    * 
from( -- marks the start of the inner query
    select 
        sum(d.Use_Qty) as total 
    from MoryaSales m 
    inner join DailyFarmEntry d 
        on m.batchID = d.FarmID 
    where 
        m.batchID = @FarmID 
        and d.FarmID = @FarmID 
        and m.Tr_Type = @InType 
        and d.In_Type = @InType 
        and m.Item_Name = @ItemName 
        and d.ItemName = @ItemName
    )t -- You need to put an alias for this inner query to prevent the error from happening.
END
```

Comment: As @Martin Smith have said, `RETURN` is unnecessary.

Comment: Bingo. The alias is the issue.

Comment: @mukesh `t` is missing at last

Comment: See `)t --this`. `t` is missing. It's very good practice to format your code for easy debugging.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar sir "M" and "D" is my alias name and where to add "t"

Comment: The inner query (the query inside the first `from`). You need an alias on that.

Comment: @wewesthemenace sir i added "from MoryaSales m 
    inner join DailyFarmEntry d"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing alias for Table and Remove RETURN

```
 select (sum((m.Item_Qty)) - total) As InStock,* from
    (select sum(d.Use_Qty) as total from MoryaSales m 
    inner join DailyFarmEntry d on m.batchID = d.FarmID 
    where m.batchID = @FarmID and d.FarmID = @FarmID 
    and m.Tr_Type = @InType and d.In_Type = @InType 
    and m.Item_Name = @ItemName and d.ItemName = @ItemName)d 
                                                           ^
```

Comment: sir i give the alise name for table "DailyFarmEntry d" so where is the missing the alias name

Comment: for your derived table